# Some doubts modelling some features for the libsvm/scikit-learn library in python

Tags: python, dictionary, scikit-learn, libsvm

I have scraped a lot of ebay titles like this one:

```
Apple iPhone 5 White 16GB Dual-Core
```

and I have manually tagged all of them in this way

```
B M C S NA
```

where B=Brand (Apple) M=Model (iPhone 5) C=Color (White) S=Size (Size) NA=Not Assigned (Dual Core)

Now I need to train a SVM classifier using the libsvm library in python to learn the sequence patterns that occur in the ebay titles.

I need to extract new value for that attributes (Brand, Model, Color, Size) by considering the problem as a classification one. In this way I can predict new models.

I want to represent these features to use them as input to the libsvm library. I work in python :D.

> 1. Identity of the current word

I think that I can interpret it in this way

```
0 --> Brand
1 --> Model
2 --> Color
3 --> Size 
4 --> NA
```

If I know that the word is a Brand I will set that variable to 1 (true). It is ok to do it in the training test (because I have tagged all the words) but how can I do that for the test set? I don't know what is the category of a word (this is why I'm learning it :D).

> 2. N-gram substring features of current word (N=4,5,6)

No Idea, what does it means?

> 3. Identity of 2 words before the current word.

How can I model this feature?

Considering the legend that I create for the 1st feature I have 5^(5) combination)

```
00 10 20 30 40
01 11 21 31 41
02 12 22 32 42
03 13 23 33 43
04 14 24 34 44
```

How can I convert it to a format that the libsvm (or scikit-learn) can understand?

```
4. Membership to the 4 dictionaries of attributes
```

Again how can I do it? Having 4 dictionaries (for color, size, model and brand) I thing that I must create a bool variable that I will set to true if and only if I have a match of the current word in one of the 4 dictionaries.

> 5. Exclusive membership to dictionary of brand names

I think that like in the 4. feature I must use a bool variable. Do you agree?

If this question lacks some info please read my previous question at this address: [Support vector machine in Python using libsvm example of features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30991592/support-vector-machine-in-python-using-libsvm-example-of-features)

Last doubt: If I have a multi token value like iPhone 5... I must tag iPhone like a brand and 5 also like a brand or is better to tag {iPhone 5} all as a brand??

In the test dataset iPhone and 5 will be 2 separates word... so what is better to do?

Comment: Could you make you question (more) understandable? See [ask]

Comment: In common English usage NA = Not Applicable so this may not be the best name for one of your classifiers esp. since number of cores could be 1/single, 2/dual, 4/quad _and possibly more in the future_ it is not something that you would normally wish to represent as a bool. (You could use 0 for Not Specified).

Comment: Brand, Model, Color and Size are all the attributes that I want to learn.. I will mark all others with NA that stands for not assigned. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason that the solution proposed to you in the previous question had Insufficient results (I assume) - is that the feature were poor for this problem.

If I understand correctly, What you want is the following:

given the sentence -

> Apple iPhone 5 White 16GB Dual-Core

You to get-

> B M C S NA

The problem you are describing here is equivalent to [part of speech tagging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part-of-speech_tagging) (POS) in Natural Language Processing.

Consider the following sentence in English:

> We saw the yellow dog

The task of POS is giving the appropriate tag for each word. In this case:

> We(PRP) saw(VBD) the(DT) yellow(JJ) dog(NN)

Don't invest time on understanding the tags in English here, since I give it here only to show you that your problem and POS are equal.

Before I explain how to solve it using SVM, I want to make you aware of other approaches: consider the sentence `Apple iPhone 5 White 16GB Dual-Core` as test data. The tag you set to the word `Apple` must be given as input to the tagger when you are tagging the word `iPhone`. However, After you tag the word a word, you will not change it. Hence, models that are doing sequance tagging usually recievces better results. The easiest example is Hidden Markov Models (HMM). [Here](https://people.cs.umass.edu/~mccallum/courses/inlp2004/lect10-tagginghmm1.pdf) is a short intro to HMM in POS.

Now we model this problem as classification problem. Lets define what is a window -

```
`W-2,W-1,W0,W1,W2`
```

Here, we have a window of size 2. When classifying the word `W0`, we will need the features of all the words in the window (concatenated). Please note that for the first word of the sentence we will use:

```
`START-2,START-1,W0,W1,W2`
```

In order to model the fact that this is the first word. for the second word we have:

```
`START-1,W-1,W0,W1,W2`
```

And similarly for the words at the end of the sentence. The tags `START-2`,`START-1`,`STOP1`,`STOP2` must be added to the model two.

Now, Lets describe what are the features used for tagging W0:

```
Features(W-2),Features(W-1),Features(W0),Features(W1),Features(W2)
```

The features of a token should be the word itself, and the tag (given to the previous word). We shall use binary features.

## **Example - how to build the feature representation:**

#### **Step 1 - building the word representation for each token**:

Lets take a window size of 1. When classifying a token, we use `W-1,W0,W1`. Say you build a dictionary, and gave every word in the corpus a number:

```
n['Apple'] = 0
n['iPhone 5'] = 1
n['White'] = 2
n['16GB'] = 3
n['Dual-Core'] = 4
n['START-1'] = 5
n['STOP1'] = 6
```

#### **Step 2 - feature token for each tag**:

we create features for the following tags:

```
n['B'] = 7 
n['M'] = 8
n['C'] = 9 
n['S'] = 10 
n['NA'] = 11
n['START-1'] = 12
n['STOP1'] = 13
```

Lets build a feature vector for `START-1,Apple,iPhone 5`: the first token is a word with known tag (`START-1` will always have the tag `START-1`). So the features for this token are:

```
(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0)
```

(The features that are 1: having the word `START-1`, and tag `START-1`)

For the token `Apple`:

```
(1,0,0,0,0,0,0)
```

Note that we use already-calculated-tags feature for every word before W0 (since we have already calculated it) . Similarly, the features of the token `iPhone 5`:

```
(0,1,0,0,0,0,0)
```

#### **Step 3  concatenate all the features**:

Generally, the features for 1-window will be:

```
word(W-1),tag(W-1),word(W0),word(W1)
```

Regarding your question - I would use one more tag - `number` - so that when you tag the word `5` (since you split the title by space), the feature `W0` will have a 1 on some number feature, and 1 in `W-1`'s `model` tag - in case the previous token was tagged correctly as model.

#### To sum up, what you should do:

1. give a number to each word in the data
2. build feature representation for the train data (using the tags you already calculated manually)
3. train a model
4. label the test data

## **Final Note - a Warm Tip For Existing Code:**

You can find POS tagger implemented in python [here](https://honnibal.wordpress.com/2013/09/11/a-good-part-of-speechpos-tagger-in-about-200-lines-of-python/). It includes explanation of the problem and code, and it also does this feature extraction I just described for you. Additionally, they used `set` for representing the feature of each word, so the code is much simpler to read.

The data this tagger receives should look like this:

```
Apple_B iPhone_M 5_NUMBER White_C 16GB_S Dual-Core_NA
```

The feature extraction is doing in this manner (see more at the link above):

```
def get_features(i, word, context, prev):
    '''Map tokens-in-contexts into a feature representation, implemented as a
    set. If the features change, a new model must be trained.'''
    def add(name, *args):
        features.add('+'.join((name,) + tuple(args)))

    features = set()
    add('bias') # This acts sort of like a prior
    add('i suffix', word[-3:])
    add('i-1 tag', prev)
    add('i word', context[i])
    add('i-1 word', context[i-1])
    add('i+1 word', context[i+1])
    return features
```

For the example above:

```
context = ["Apple","iPhone","5","White","16GB","Dual-Core"]
prev = "B"
i = 1
word = "iPhone"
```

Generally, `word` is the str of the current word, `context` is a the title split into list, and `prev` is the tag you received for the previous word.

I use this code in the past, it works fast with great results.
Hope its clear, Have fun tagging!

Comment: Thanks for the answer... But could you make a proof of concept of the implementation?

Comment: @UsiUsi what exactly?

Comment: I the previous correlated question they also add to the explanation a proof of concept... You said that you have tested it (with different data of course)... could you post the code?

Comment: If you read my answer, you probably figured that POS is the problem you are dealing with. If you wish to build your own feature extraction mechanism - you are welcome. On the other hand, I gave here a link to code which receives 97% accuracy on POS. The code itself isn't enough?

Comment: @UsiUsi did you try it?

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't understand your explanation and your approach. That's why I have asked for a sample code.

Comment: @UsiUsi The notion of what I wrote here, is that the previous solution that was given to you had lack representation. Since usually after 'Brand' appears, the 'Model' comes after, try to insert the last tag as a feature. I added an example of how the features should be extracted, and of course I'm willing to help you in future questions if you need it...

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and also (of course) for your great answer... I haven't try it yet... but I have already marked your answer as best.

Comment: laat thing.. I have a closer look at the code... but I can't understand how can I call it... can you make an example using the title of the iPhone that I have posted? what it the arg context? thanks